# Hover out bar element in a Bar Chart

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a Bar Chart and a Scatter plot in a Dash dashboard. When I hover over a bar, the Scatter plot points get filtered to only those that fall in the bucket given by the bar label. I use hoverData in a callback for that.

What I would like is when I hover out of the bar, to display all points back again.

Does anyone know how to capture such an event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already answered on the plotly forum.

In short: dcc.Graph has a property called **clear_on_unhover** which you can set to **True**. The property hoverData will then be set to None on unhover. You can get info about it with

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
help(dcc.Graph)
```

in a python console.

Source: https://community.plot.ly/t/way-to-cancel-hoverdata/12017